# Minio uploads through the web interface and API receives "Unauthorized request."

Tags: reverse-proxy, centos7, mod-security, minio

I can successfully upload files to my Minio server using mc command line client (logged in as root):

```
./mc cp roobina.jpg minio/mag
roobina.jpg:                        63.50 KiB / 63.50 KiB
```

But when I try to upload a file to a bucket using minio's own web interface I receive this error:

```
Unauthorized request.
```

When using api (in a php application using AmazonS3 libraries), I receive this error:

```
Error:Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3.***.net/clbu/public/4d/4b/d1ad580690058a636ad58e5af931541336ec.jpg"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://s3.***.net/clbu/public/4d/4b/d1ad580690058a636ad58e5af931541336ec.jpg` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
Forbidden (truncated...) Unable to parse error information from response - Error parsing XML: String could not be parsed as XML
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at different possible causes, I found that mod_security of apache (used as reverse proxy of minio:9000) was interfering with uploads causing the problem.

I disabled mod_security on the reverse proxy account and the problem is now solved.